# How to prevent c++ asio tcp server from shutdown?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

In example: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_server.cpp we always create new pointer to accept new session. If we don't, server will shutdown (in case of error). My server has a limit set of IDs and each session gets one. So when set is empty server can't respond to new session until one of IDs will free. How to prevent server from shutdown without creating additional objects and any loops? (Server can get ~1k connections until one of IDs will free and it cause creating 1k of additional objects in case of using example template).

```
void handle_accept(chat_session_ptr session,
      const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error || !setIds.empty())
    {
      session->start();
      chat_session_ptr new_session(new chat_session(io_service_, room_));
      acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
          boost::bind(&chat_server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
  }
```

Comment: End ``if`` after ``session->start();`` and in ``else`` put some kind of ``session->close();``. So when ``setIds`` is empty you will close session immidiately after it was opened, when its not - you'll start it normally, and in both cases you will still accept other connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should probably create some wait condition before accepting new connection if you're "out of ID"s.

Because, if you don't, you can simply continue accepting by making

```
  acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
      boost::bind(&chat_server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

unconditional, but you  **have a loop**: you'll be wasting resources accepting connections that you can't handle until IDs become available.

What's worse (potentially), you'll be dropping connections that you might have been able to just handle say 1ms, 10ms or 100ms later.

I'd suggest letting the OS keep such connections in the backlog - by not accepting them early.

---

Alternatively, you could accept all connections but put them into a queue if you're out of IDs (only start dropping the connections when the queue is empty). I'd consider using a semaphore to govern the pool of available ID.